# How do I install Ruby 2.6 with Chocolatey?

Tags: windows, ruby, chocolatey

I tried to list all version of Ruby but it only lists one.

```
choco list ruby --exact --all
ruby 2.7.0.1 [Approved]
1 packages found.
```

Nokogiri won't work with the latest Ruby.

```
Gem::RuntimeRequirementNotMetError: nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 2.3, <
2.7.dev. The current ruby version is 2.7.0.0.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
choco install ruby --version=2.6.5.1
choco pin add -n=ruby
```

The first command, can be found in the [Chocolatey package page](https://chocolatey.org/packages/ruby/2.6.5.1#versionhistory), clicking on *Version History* and then on the version you want install.

The second command pins the package to suppress upgrades (e.g. when running `cup all`).